# How to consolidate two Python classes containing methods with identical signatures?

Tags: python, api, rest, api-design

I'm working on a REST client library, and recently started working on adding support for sending batch messages.

However, I don't like the current design. It requires you to maintain large Client and RequestMessage classes with identical method signatures.

I am looking for a way to consolidate the two classes.

The original Client class's methods contained all the code needed to prepare and send the request:

```
class Client(object):

   def __init__(self, config):
       self.request = Request(config, "application/json")

   def create_vertex(self, data):
       path = "vertices"
       params = remove_null_values(data)
       self.request.post(path, params)
```

To add support for batch messages, I pulled out the guts of the code inside the each Client method, and put it into a separate RequestMessage class so that you can add the messages to the batch without sending it, until you're ready:

```
class Client(object):

   def __init__(self, config):
       self.request = Request(config, "application/json")
       self.message = RequestMessage(config)

   def create_vertex(self, data):
       message = self.message.create_vertex(data)
       return self.request.send(message)

   # ...more REST client methods...

   def batch(self, messages):
       path = "batch" 
       params = messages
       return self.request.post(path, params)       

class RequestMessage(object):

   def __init__(self, config):
       self.config = config

   def create_vertex(self, data):
       path = "vertices"
       params = remove_null_values(data)
       return POST, path, params

  # ...more REST client methods...
```

But I don't like the design because now you have to maintain the Client and RequestMessage class -- two large classes with identical signatures.

Here's what the Batch class looks like:

```
class Batch(object):

   def __init__(self, client):
       self.client = client
       self.messages = []

   def add(self, message):
       self.messages.append(message)

   def send(self):
       return self.client.batch(self.messages)
```

Here's example usage for creating a vertex on the server:

```
>>> client = Client(config)
>>> vertex = client.create_vertex({'name':'James'})
```

Here's example usage for creating a batch of vertices on the server:

```
>>> message1 = client.message.create_vertex({'name':'James'})
>>> message2 = client.message.create_vertex({'name':'Julie'})
>>> batch = Batch(client)
>>> batch.add(message1)
>>> batch.add(message2)
>>> batch.send()
```

Batch is used less frequently than Client so I want to make the normal Client interface easiest to use.

Here's one idea, but I'm not quite sure how to achieve it or if something else would be better:

```
   >>> vertex = client.create_vertex(data)
   >>> message = client.create_vertex(data).message()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My personal preference is an API like:

```
client.create_vertex({'name':'James'}) # single
client.create_vertex([{'name':'James'}, {'name':'Julie'}]) # batch
```

That way you use the exact same function, you're just giving it more data.  Typical usage would probably look more like:

```
batch = []
batch.append({'name':'James'})
batch.append({'name':'Julie'})
client.create_vertex(batch)
```

Comment: Hi Karl - Batch need to be able to include different commands -- create_vertex, create_edge, index_vertex. I'll look at setting batch mode on the client.

Comment: Yeah, I could subclass Client to make BatchClient and have it add commands to the batch list rather than immediately sending each request.

Answer (score 1):

I would agree with @Karl with some modifications

```
client.create_vertex({'name':'James'}) # single
client.create_vertex({'name':'James'}, {'name':'Julie'}) # batch

batch = []
batch.append({'name':'James'})
batch.append({'name':'Julie'})
client.create_vertex(*batch)
```

That way you don't have to check the type of your input. Easier to write, easier to use.